# WP7 WebClient HTTPs Not Found error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, https, webclient

I was looking for an answer, but unfortunately neither could help me. I need the Windows Phone 7 to connect to the server using WebClient and https, so I use the following code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.UploadStringCompleted += ....
wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("https://path.to.page/api"), "POST", "data=data");
```

After this, code break wit error "Not Found", but when i open page in browser it's everthing ok.
Do you have anyone a solution how to connect via https? Http works fine. I also tried credentials. I also tried the advice of others here, but nothing is working.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Dont you have a certificate problem? Try opening the url in the wp browser... The pageshould be accessed directly without warning..

Comment: Yes you have right, there is a confirmation with untrusted certificate. But i need used for testing purpouse only self-signed certificate. It is possible?

Comment: You have to install the self-signed certificate on your emulator or device by sending it by email or browsing with IE to it...

Comment: Export the certificate in Microsoft Mangement Console (Start -> run: mmc). Btw: see http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http

Answer (score -1):

Probably your problem is with the line below

```
wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("https://path.to.page/api"), "POST", "data=data");
```

try adding your parameters to your uri like below

```
var params = "data=data";
wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("https://path.to.page/api?" + params), "POST");
```

And definitely use a program like fiddler to watch your requests from the emulator.

Hope that helps I didn't test it with https but it shouldn't be any different than with http. I couldn't see anything else that could be wrong with the code.